# Why do we pass nn.Module as an argument to class definition for neural nets?

Tags: python, machine-learning, module, pytorch

I want to understand why we pass torch.nn.Module as a argument when we define the class for a neural network like GAN's

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size, f):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.map1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.map2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.map3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
        self.f = f
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
```

simple means the `Generator` class will inherit the `nn.Module` class, it is not an argument.

However, the dunder **init** method:

```
def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size, f):
```

Has self which is why you may consider this as an argument.

Well this is Python class instance `self`. There were tinkering battles should it stay or should it go, but Guido, explained in his blog [`why it has to stay`](https://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html).

Answer (score 1):

We are essentially defining the class 'Generator' with the nn.Module (with its functionalities). In programming we refer to this as inheritence (with the `super(Generator, self).__init__()`).

You can read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas, I am still unsure about why we are trying to inherit the methods and the properties of  nn.Module because we can easily use nn.function_name to use functions we want as we have already imported torch.nn